# How do I scale the image down on mobile device and get rid of the white margin space?

Tags: html, css

How do I scale the image down to fit the size of the mobile/tablet devices? There also appears to be a white margin and a horizontal scroll bar when its minimized to 768px and lower. Do I fix this in the bootstrap.css code? What am I doing wrong?

http://f13-preview.awardspace.net/groupeezz.dx.am/groupeezz3/index.html

I want it somewhat like this when you scale it down. I adjusted the media queries, but its not showing up nicely.

http://atomtickets.com/

Answer (score 0):

To scale images, use percentages. Ex...

```
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Without seeing all of your css, my best guess to remove with right margin would be to start your css document with a reset

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

When you use @media rules to build for mobile or table, be conscious of what exists higher up in the document. So let's say you want to style all images like this on desktop and on mobile you want to get rid of the top margin.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

On mobile, you actually need to specify that you want the margin-top to be zero. For example, this will still display margin-top: 200px...

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
}
```

Whereas this will actually remove the top margin on mobile.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Happy to explain anything further if you need it! :)
    }

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have used 100% for the width and height. It's still not working.

Comment: I also fixed the white margin space. I didn't realize that it was so easy. -.- lol I just went into the row class in the bootstrap.css. At least I'm learning lol..

Will you also be able to tell me what exactly is this guy saying? I'm so lost. https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/something-is-wrong-with-the-navbar-in-the-css-code-how-do-i-fix-this/222799/3

if he's telling me the same thing you just told me, than I fixed the problem with the horiztonal bar and the white right white margin. 

I also thought row classes are the parent of the column classes. It's how my teacher told us to do.